# Self controller nil webview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm pretty new to Swift development, or iOS development for that matter.
I'm making an app thats mostly the display of a webview with a default URL, with firebase setup in order to send notifications with URLs to change that webview.

So far I've managed to:

- Make the successful reception of notifications through firebase with a key for the url passing;
- Usage of Reachability to display an alert in case the user forgot to turn his wifi on;
- Usage of a progressIndicator

All of this was smooth sailing except for the change of the webView url.

This is my viewDidAppear

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var fakeLogo: UIImageView!

let reachability = Reachability()!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){

    if reachability.isReachable {
        if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
            print("Reachable via WiFi")
        } else {
            print("Reachable via Cellular")
        }

        let myUrl = NSURL(string:"https://www.btp.pt")
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL);

        webView.delegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(myRequest as URLRequest)

    } else {
        //print("Network not reachable")
        let alert = showNetworkDialogHelper()
        alert.showNetworkDialog(fromController: self)
    }

}
```

This is my changeUrl function with is also in ViewController

```
    func changeWebviewURL(url: String) {
    print("changeWebviewURL : \(url)")

    //print(self.webView) returns nil and
    //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

    let stringUrl = url
    let requestUrl = URL(string: stringUrl);
    let myRequestUrl = URLRequest(url: requestUrl! as URL);
    self.webView!.loadRequest(myRequestUrl)

}
```

The simple print of self.webView here in this function returns me a nil. And that's what I've been trying to overcome but can't.

Could you please help me?

Comment: did you check requestUrl for nil?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Yes I did but the error comes even before that. Even if I don't declare the 4 last lines, the error still occurs.

Comment: Is the webView in Storyboard or are you creating it programatically.?

Comment: @Rishab Yes, it's in Storyboard. I've updated the code above.

Comment: try making the webView property as strong.

Comment: @Rishab Thank you for your reply Rishab. As I said, I'm a newbie here. Can you explain to me how can I do that?

Comment: Change `@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!` to `@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!`

Comment: @Rishab, thanks for your reply, I made it strong. And the error persists to occur.

Comment: Can you share the project??

Comment: *self.webView* is not defined anywhere in your question so there's no way to  know how it's initially populated/defined. If it's not, then that's why it's nil.

Comment: @Jay thank you for your reply. Isn't that what IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView! Is doing?

Comment: My apologies. I meant to type *Reachability* as if it is nil, the code in that block will not execute. Also, double check to make sure the webView is connected to the actual webView in your storyboard. It's not clear when *changeWebviewURL* is called so that could be an issue as well. There's a mix of older legacy NS code and current Swift 3 code so I would suggest updating to Swift 3 for all those calls. Also, as a side note, it's generally a good idea to reference class level vars with *self.*. I posted an answer with working Swift 3 code.

Comment: Oh - the code in your question actually works (I copy and pasted it into a new project) however, I commented out the Reachability lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ViewController code that's updated for Swift 3 and has been tested. I've omitted the Reachability var as that may be a cause of the issues and it's undefined in the question.

You'll notice I added a button to the view in the storyboard with an action that changes the URL the webView is pointing to.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
       self.changeWebviewURL(url: "http://www.apple.com")
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
       let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
       self.webView.loadRequest(request)
       self.webView.delegate = self
   }

   func changeWebviewURL(url: String) {
       print("changeWebviewURL : \(url)")

       let myUrl = URL(string: url)
       let request = URLRequest(url: myUrl!)
       self.webView.loadRequest(request)
       print(self.webView)
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```